# Show icon or text next to the title - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want to make  that if a post will contains a specific category / tag, then i want show icon or text displayed next to the title. How can I do this? That's all I need, and I can't find any plugins, so I'd probably have to add my own code to the Custom Functions plugin or somewhere else. My knowledge of a function description or anything related to PHP is very little. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple idea, you define the category in the array. The value is the same name of the category and the image.

If the category name is in the field, then load the image (.jpg) and return the html string

PHP Function

```
<?php 

function imageToCat(){
    // get the category variable from WordPress
    $categories = get_the_category();

    // definite array image
    $category =[
        'Allgemein','Cat B'
    ];

    if(in_array($categories[0]->cat_name,$category)){
        // If the cat_name is in array
        return '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/image_path/'.$categories[0]->cat_name.'.jpg" alt="" >';

    } // else { echo 'not in Array!';}
}
?>
```

You can call the function in your HTML file with as an an example

```
<header>
    <h1><?php echo imageToCat();?>  Your Title</h1>
</header>
```